# Modify Postgres query to use generate_series for overall summation over each of several consecutive range intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql, range, aggregate-functions, generate-series

I'm still quite new with SQL, coming from an ORM-centric environment, so please be patient with me.

Provided with a table in the form of:

```sql
CREATE TABLE event (id int, order_dates tsrange, flow int);
INSERT INTO event VALUES
    (1,'[2021-09-01 10:55:01,2021-09-04 15:16:01)',50),
    (2,'[2021-08-15 20:14:27,2021-08-18 22:19:27)',36),
    (3,'[2021-08-03 12:51:47,2021-08-05 11:28:47)',41),
    (4,'[2021-08-17 09:14:30,2021-08-20 13:57:30)',29),
    (5,'[2021-08-02 20:29:07,2021-08-04 19:19:07)',27),
    (6,'[2021-08-26 02:01:13,2021-08-26 08:01:13)',39),
    (7,'[2021-08-25 23:03:25,2021-08-27 03:22:25)',10),
    (8,'[2021-08-12 23:40:24,2021-08-15 08:32:24)',26),
    (9,'[2021-08-24 17:19:59,2021-08-29 00:48:59)',5),
    (10,'[2021-09-01 02:01:17,2021-09-02 12:31:17)',48); -- etc
```

the query below does the following:

(here, `'the range'` is `2021-08-03T00:00:00` from to `2021-08-04T00:00:00`)

1. For each event that overlaps with `the range`
2. Trim the Lower and Upper timestamp values of `order_dates` to the bounds of `the range`
3. Multiply the remaining duration of each applicable event by the `event.flow` value
4. Sum all of the multiplied values for a final single value output

> > Basically, I get all of the events that overlap `the range`, but only calculate the total value based on the portion of each event that is *within* `the range`.

```sql
SELECT SUM("total_value")
FROM
    (SELECT (EXTRACT(epoch
        FROM (LEAST(UPPER("event"."order_dates"), '2021-08-04T00:00:00'::timestamp) - GREATEST(LOWER("event"."order_dates"), '2021-08-03T00:00:00'::timestamp)))::INTEGER * "event"."flow") AS "total_value"
    FROM "event"
    WHERE "event"."order_dates" && tsrange('2021-08-03T00:00:00'::timestamp, '2021-08-04T00:00:00'::timestamp, '[)')
    GROUP BY "event"."id",
        GREATEST(LOWER("event"."order_dates"), '2021-08-03T00:00:00'::timestamp),
        LEAST(UPPER("event"."order_dates"), '2021-08-04T00:00:00'::timestamp),
        EXTRACT(epoch
            FROM (LEAST(UPPER("event"."order_dates"), '2021-08-04T00:00:00'::timestamp) - GREATEST(LOWER("event"."order_dates"), '2021-08-03T00:00:00'::timestamp)))::INTEGER, (EXTRACT(epoch
                FROM (LEAST(UPPER("event"."order_dates"), '2021-08-04T00:00:00'::timestamp) - GREATEST(LOWER("event"."order_dates"), '2021-08-03T00:00:00'::timestamp)))::INTEGER * "event"."flow")) subquery
```

The DB<>Fiddle demonstrating this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jMBtKKRS33Qf2FEoY5EdPA/1

This query started out as a complex set of django annotations and aggregation, and I have simplified it to remove the parts not necessary for this question.

---

So with the above I get a single total value over the input range (in this case a 1-day range).

But I want to be able to use `generate_series` to perform this same overall summation to each of several consecutive range intervals

e.g.: query for the total during each of the following ranges:

```
['2021-08-01T00:00:00', '2021-08-02T00:00:00')
['2021-08-02T00:00:00', '2021-08-03T00:00:00')
['2021-08-03T00:00:00', '2021-08-04T00:00:00')
['2021-08-04T00:00:00', '2021-08-05T00:00:00')
```

This is somewhat related to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69023292/generate-timestamp-ranges-over-an-interval-and-query-for-all-overlapping-events), but since the timestamps for the queried range are used in so many places within the query, I'm pretty lost for how to do this.

Any help/direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qm4F7qqWZMrtXtMejimVJr/1.

Basically what I did was to prepare the ranges with a CTE up-front, then select from that table expression with a `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` of your original query. Next, I replaced all occurrences of 20210803 with `lower(target_range)` and 20210804 with `upper(target_range)`, then added the GROUP BY of target_range. Note that only those ranges that overlap at least one row in the input will appear in the output; change the cross join to a LEFT JOIN to always see your input ranges in the output, even if value is null. (If so, `ON TRUE` is fine for the join condition, since you already do the filtering the WHERE of the inner subquery.)

Comment: AdamKG, thank you so much for this! Since I wanted all ranges, including those with nulls, I took your advice. Conveniently, the data set I initially provided has a no entries for 20210801, so I was able to immediately see if it worked - and it did! Here's the modified db-fiddle in case anyone needs it in the future: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qm4F7qqWZMrtXtMejimVJr/2